# Wordpress Site As Subversion Working Copy

Tags: wordpress, svn

I am currently developing a site based on WordPress (3.3) and am having an issue keeping it up to date properly in subversion (my personal svn server), wondering if I could get any help/guidance on how to handle this. I have a working copy checked out, and everything is working fine, accept for when I update a plugin and/or WordPress itself...here's an example for the Woocommerce plugin (hopefully I explain this well enough):

1. Woocommerce notifies me of update
2. I update the plugin using the WordPress dashboard
3. WordPress deletes all files in the wp-content/upgrade directory, and the plugins/woocommerce directory (including the .svn folders).
4. I then try and either do an svn add and/or svn commit and get errors about the upgrade and woocommerce directory's 'working copy admin area missing' plus a whole bunch of other problems.

I want to be able to keep this WordPress site in subversion and keep the plugins directory updated, so that I can eventually do an export when I'm ready to move the site to my server, but this is proving to be exceptionally difficult (I can re-checkout and replace the .svn directories for each of the WordPress folders that are missing them, but there are a lot of folders, and is very tedious. I can ignore the upgrade and plugin folders, but then they don't get updated and my export won't go as planned...what should I do?

Comment: I hope, you know, that WC-root inside http-root is very insecure and dangerous?

Comment: Yes, I do...it's not in the http-root...sorry if that was not clear in the above :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that will help a lot is to upgrade your client to Subversion 1.7. Instead of a .svn folder in each folder, it has a single .svn folder in the root of the working copy and will keep better track of things.

After you upgrade your client, do `svn upgrade` at the root of your working copy. Note that this is irreversible and incompatible with older versions of SVN.

The SVN server does not have to be upgraded for this, only the client.

Comment: Here is a guide on updating one's Subversion client on Mac OS X : http://redfinsolutions.com/blog/update-subversion-mac-os-x